# SFMC not sending data to a custom activity endpoint (REST type)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

I have a custom activity that isn't getting any data from MC. 
Param1/param2 are coming from activity UI form, Subscriber key is hardcoded in config.json.

Is my configuration valid? Publish.url is working.

Thank you for any help.

```
 {
  "workflowApiVersion": "1.1",  
  "type": "REST",
  "lang": {
    "en-US": {
        "name": "CA DEV",
        "description": ""
    }
  },  
  "metaData": {
    "icon": "https://url/icon.png",
    "category": "message"
  },
  "arguments": {
    "execute": {         
      "inArguments": [{"SubscriberKey": "{{Contact.Key}}"}, {"param1": "value1"}, {"param2": "value2"}],
      "outArguments": [],      
      "url": "https://url/offers",             
      "verb": "POST",
      "body": "",
      "header": "",
      "format": "json",
      "useJwt": true,
      "timeout": 10000
    }

  },
  "configurationArguments": {
        "publish": {        
      "url" : "https://url/publish" 
        }  
  },
  "wizardSteps": [
    { "label": "Parameters", "key": "params" }
  ],
  "userInterfaces": {    
    "configModal": {
      "height": 400,
      "width": 700,
      "fullscreen": false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the wrong URL for execute object. **Instead of key "execute" I used "offers".**